# I can't shout at the Grey Beards?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I finally got to the Grey Beards in Skyrim they told me to shout at them. I held down "RB" because that's what it told me to do in "help", but my character didn't shout. The strange thing is I picked up the language in Bleak Falls Barrow and absorbed a dragon soul. If I can't shout at the Grey Beards, what do I do?

Comment: Look at your controls settings, maybe Shout isn't mapped to RB.

Comment: Have you unlocked the shout in the magic menu? If you're not sure, go to Magic -> Shouts -> Unrelenting Force. You should know the first word, but if it is greyed out, you need to spend the dragon soul first by pressing (X). For example, in [random image I got from google](http://i.ytimg.com/vi/iwD332i_-f4/maxresdefault.jpg), "Ice" is unlocked, while "Flesh" and "Statue" are not. (I'll make it an answer if it helped.)

Comment: I actually just found that out you have to go to the magic section then equip the Unrelenting voice.

Comment: Of course though,when I finally figure it out I am super far away from the grey beards now

Answer (score 9):

I found out that if you have absorbed a dragon soul and you have learned the shout from Bleak Falls Barrow (or other places) to get the Unrelenting voice go to the Magic Menu and it should be there. Equip it and hold down "RB" when your with the Grey Beards.